# Creating a Dialog within a Fragment using a list and alert dialog.builder

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-alertdialog

I've been trying to implement a dialog inside a fragment for a few days now for a movie information app. The dialog is supposed appear once you click a "Sort order settings" menu button in the top right. It SHOULD appear with two options to sort the list of movies; most popular and by rating.

According to the stack trace and the debug logs I put, it lots like the code goes through the whole alert builder process and crashes on the 'return' line of the alert dialog builder(Line 179). Stack trace reads as follows:

```
07-24 10:10:09.586 28650-28650/com.example.android.popmovies W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
07-24 10:10:09.588 28650-28650/com.example.android.popmovies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.android.popmovies, PID: 28650
                                                                           android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                               at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:966)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:942)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:930)
                                                                               at com.example.android.popmovies.MainActivityFragment$sortingMenuFragment.onCreateDialog(MainActivityFragment.java:179)
```

From researching online and seeing how others have fixed the issue, I've tweaked and implemented multiple things in the code according to the android documentation, but it still doesn't work. Links I used found here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

AlertDialog section of:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

I feel like my code is identical to the android documentation and can't find what I'm missing. ANY help or advice is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance. My relevant code is below.

My fragment code:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.popmovies.utilities.FetchUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivityFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    final String BASE_URL_MOVIES_POPULAR = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?";

    // TODO will be used when option sort feature is done
    final String BASE_URL_MOVIES_TOP_RATED = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?";

    // TODO remember to remove API key before submitting project!!!! **************************
    final String API_KEY = "api_key=2499d4a4f8ad842fb5ed41d5c6542d79";

    private static MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

    // Variable to determine if list is sorted already
    // 0 == most popular / 1 == top rated
    private static int sortOrder = 0;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_main, container, false);

        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Movie>());
        GridView gridView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {
            new MovieDatabaseTask().execute(BASE_URL_MOVIES_POPULAR + API_KEY);
        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // TODO eventually enter the "details fragment"
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Fragment transaction started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootview;
    }

    public static class MovieDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Movie>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String searchUrlString = urls[0];
            URL searchUrl;
            String movieDatabaseSearchResults = null;
            List<Movie> movieList = null;

            try {
                searchUrl = new URL(searchUrlString);
                movieDatabaseSearchResults = FetchUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
                movieList = FetchUtils.extractMoviesFromResponse(movieDatabaseSearchResults);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return movieList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movieList) {

            // clear previous movie data, if any
            movieAdapter.clear();

            if (movieList != null && !movieList.isEmpty()) {
                movieAdapter.addAll(movieList);
                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate menu with the sort settings
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item click here
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_sort) {
            // CALL DIALOG HERE using helper method
            showDialog();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // TODO FIX THISSSSSS dialog thinggg
    public static class sortingMenuFragment extends DialogFragment {

        public static sortingMenuFragment newInstance(int title) {
            sortingMenuFragment frag = new sortingMenuFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        // Creates the dialog that will display when helper method is called
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("onCreateDialog", " started!!");

            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(title)
                    .setItems(R.array.sorting_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
                            switch (which) {
                                case 0:
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "position 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "position 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Log.d("about to return ", "the dialog");
            return builder.create(); // program crashes on this line (according to stack trace)
        }
    }

    // Helper method that shows the dialog
    void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = sortingMenuFragment.newInstance(
                R.string.sort_by);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

String array the populates list for dialog:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="sorting_array">
    <item>Most Popular</item>
    <item>Top Rated</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

a first simple test: put the string array in the strings.xml file;

besides I've tested your code removing the toast and works

Comment: Interesting! The code from the Android documentation has the strings being called from an arrays.xml file, which is why I tried it that way. So instead of the toast, you left that area of the code blank?

Comment: I put the string array inside my strings.xml file. I also tried removing the toast but the app still crashes. I cleaned the app, re-compiled, invalidated the cache and restarted, but the app still crashes. =(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got the home task from 'Hexagon' my friend.... I've already did it, the whole app they ask for , so I can help you in private to avoid too much traffic in this thread... Contact me in private if it's the case ☺️

By the way, it look like clean project could help to resolve missing resources issues

Comment: Good tip! Will try later tonight when I get a chance. I'm doing a project from Udacity's Android program.

Comment: Cool, let me know if clean helped (you can also try to 'invalidate caches and restart' function of android studio it always to do so once a while)

Comment: tried both cleaning and invalidate and restart. Both didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think I know what is the problem.Instead of passing as 'int' the text, choose of the following:
1. pass a String via the bundle
2. get the string directly 
and then set it as title
Many time, for example when trying to set a TextView text via 'R' resources, this exception occurred.Try it and let me know..(even try it hardcoded to isolate the bug, and after bug resolution find a way to satisfy this solution with your flow)